# what's the performance impact causing from the large size of Apache's access.log?

Tags: apache

If the logs file like access.log or error.log gets very large, will the large-size problem impact the performance of Apache running or user accessing? From my understanding, Apache doesn't read entire logs into memory, but just make use of filehandle to write. Right? If so, I don't have to remove the logs manually every time when it's large enough except for the filesystem issue. Please help and correct me if I'm wrong. Or is there any Apache Log I/O issue I'm supposed to take care when running it?

Thx very much

Answer (score 2):

Well, i totally agree with you. Per my understanding apache access the log files using handlers and just append the new message at the end of the file. That's way a huge log file will not make the difference  when has to do with writing to the file. But may be if you want to access the file or open it with a kind of logging monitoring tool then the huge size will slowdown the process of reading the file.

So i would suggest you to use log rotation to have an overall better end result.

This suggestion is directly form the apche web site.

> Log Rotation

On even a moderately busy server, the quantity of information stored in the log files is very large. The access log file typically grows 1 MB or more per 10,000 requests. It will consequently be necessary to periodically rotate the log files by moving or deleting the existing logs. This cannot be done while the server is running, because Apache will continue writing to the old log file as long as it holds the file open. Instead, the server must be restarted after the log files are moved or deleted so that it will open new log files.

[From the Apache Software Foundation site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html)